# After upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 vim does not work... can't install it!

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, python, vim

After upgrading Ubuntu, I just notice that vim is not working (actually deleting from Ubuntu)

So I tried to re-installing it using this command:

```
$ sudo apt install vim
```

And the result is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vim : Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.4~rc1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I have Vim back?!

edited after N0rbert comment:

```
vim:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
libpython3.6:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.6.7-1~18.04
  Version table:
     3.6.7-1~18.04 500
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.6.6-3~18.04.york0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.6.5-3 500
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please run `sudo apt update`, then retry and add output of `apt-cache policy vim libpython3.6` to the question.

Comment: I edited the post @N0rbert

Comment: Related: [Revert PPA Python installation to official after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/q/1092566/301745)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this ppa - https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6

Then install it -

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt install vim
```

Comment: again this message:
vim : Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.4~rc1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Maybe I'm out of my depth, but I don't see why this would be necessary. `libpython3.6` is in the default repos. See OP's edit for details.

Comment: You can try using the command - sudo apt update --fix-missing